# Is there a way I can setAdapter and setMessage at the same time for MaterialAlertDialogBuilder?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog, android-adapter

I want body text to appear above a list of views inside dialog from MaterialAlertDialogBuilder. I tried setting body text and adapter but it only resulted in showing the body text, ex1.

```java
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder builder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(-)
builder.setMessage(R.string.ex1)
builder.setAdapter(adapter, new OnClickListener() { - }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setTitle](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/dialog/MaterialAlertDialogBuilder#setTitle(int)) method of the MaterialAlertDialogBuilder.

```java
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder builder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder( - )
builder.setTitle(R.string.ex1)
builder.setAdapter(adapter, new OnClickListener() { - }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I want different text for the title and body.

Comment: You can achieve what you want by applying style to the body text and adapter text. But for things like this I prefer custom dialog :)